# Protobuf-net RPC with byte[]?

Tags: encryption, udp, rpc, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I've been using protobuf-net to communicate object state data in standard protobuf-net fashion.

I've been serializing the object, getting a byte[] array out, encrypting the array and sending it out via UDP.  The client then gets the byte[] array, decrypts and deserializes the object and everything works wonderfully.

I like doing it this way because we can have a number of data viewer terminals that might not always have the best or most reliable of connections.

Now I need to add some RPC mechanisms.  I'd very much like to utilize the same kind of feature-set (serialize, encrypt and shoot out over UDP).

I already have an interface, and have WCF and XML-RPC hooked up to it.  I've looked at utilizing protobuf-net as a WCF endpoint, and I'm not too sure that it's what I'm looking for.  I'd really like to be able to wrap everything up in the encryption scheme that I already have and reuse a lot of other code.

I've looked at the basic http RPC examples in protobuf-net and have been looking around for a way to get a byte[] for RPC use.    I'd be willing to write a good chunk of the code; I just don't really have a good idea where to start.

Any ideas?

edit:

So here's how I normally send out my status message.  Which is just some variables serialized with protobuf-net

```
    ProtoBuf.Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(mStream, Common.Share, ProtoBuf.PrefixStyle.Fixed32);  

    byte[] ptext2 = RNGBytes.Concat(mStream.ToArray()).ToArray();  

    byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Convert.ToBase64String(RNGBytes) + plainText);  

    cryptoStream.Write(ptext2, 0, ptext2.Length);

    // Finish encrypting.
    cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

    // Now we're done with the memory stream, let's turn it back into an array of bytes.
    byte[] cipherTextBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();

    foreach (IPEndPoint iep in BroadcastToIPs)
    {
        U.Send(cryptoStream.GetBuffer(), (int)mStream.Length, iep);
    }

    // Close both streams.
    memoryStream.Close();
    cryptoStream.Close();
```

Now I have an interface, something like

`public interface
{
void SetMovementMode(int Axis, int Mode);
.....
}`

Does anyone have any ideas on how to wrap that one up and send it out in a similar fashion, with being able to encrypt it, etc?

Comment: One thought I've been having:  Use an implementation sumilar to the [rpc.proto](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-socket-rpc/source/browse/trunk/proto/rpc.proto) from protobuf-socket-rpc Java project and use reflection to push everything back through...but I feel like I'm missing something if I were to do that.

Comment: when you say "get a byte[] for RPC use" - can you be more specific? a byte[] doesn't care much how it is used... more specifically, what step is causing the headache? what is the usage you are looking for? (I might have some things in mind, but I need to be clearer about the problem)

Comment: Edited to add extra information.

Comment: right; so - there's three options I can see... 1: code-generation, to write c# for your interface before build; 2: meta-programming (writing a concrete implementation of your interface on the fly), and 3: expression-tree parsing; I have some crude steps for each, but - doing this elegantly is far from trivial. I do have a **bery basic** RPC server in one cut of tw code, which could perhaps be adjusted... But... It isn't very pretty (I'd do it very differently if rewriting)

Comment: Yea, I did some small forays into option #2, but it quickly became very not elegant, which kind of led to my question.  The cheating way out would be using that rpc.proto from comment with some reflection.  Not optimal, but would make a good interim solution.

Comment: the odd thing is I'm writing a socket server right now, but: I decided to make it message based rather than RPC/interface-based. So there's only one API, but I simply give it different data. Very simple to code, and no abstractions or idirections to slow things down.

Comment: With protobuf-net? I don't really have a *need* for it to be RPC.  That just seemed to be the way that you were going with it.

Comment: yes; I haven't decided yet - have two working prototypes: one using inheritance of a common base-message, and the other using a marker tag

Answer (score 1):

I'm using zeroMQ with protobuf-net to do my RPC (.NET to .NET and python to .NET). ZMQ is a brokerless messaging framework that allows you to send around byte[], and build various neat architectures with minimal code. Also there are bindings for all sorts of languages.  Check out their guide [here](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall)